# Button_Alignment and position

Tags: button, flutter, position, alignment

Hello everyone please help me. i want to make a flutter signup page(design pic is given below). i code as much as i know.if i do anything else it goes wrong(my code and app result screenshot is also given below). so tell me what do i do in code for alignment of the button. just tell how the alignment/placement will be

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Travel Budget App",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: FirstView(),
    );
  }
}
class FirstView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Align(
         alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
         child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways you can achieve this.

**Using Stack:** Scaffold -> Stack -> [Positioned(top:8, right: 8), Column->[Raisedbutton1, RaisedButton2]]

**Using Column** Scaffold -> Column-> [Align(Aligment:Alignment.centerRight), Spacer(), RaisedButton1, RaisedButton2]

Read about Stack and Positioned widget if you don't understand the first option. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As @saiful-islam-adar mentioned there are multiple ways to achieve this
I used [spacer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html)

```
class FirstView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100, horizontal: 10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RoundedButton(
                      color: Colors.white, text: 'Login', onPressed: () {}),
                ],
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RoundedButton(
                      color: Colors.white, text: 'E-mail', onPressed: () {}),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  RoundedButton(
                      color: Colors.white, text: 'Facebook', onPressed: () {}),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```